# Proof Regarding Holomorphic Function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functions, solution-verification

### Problem

Suppose $f$ being a holomorphic function and $f(0)=p$ as well as $f'(0)\neq0$. Proof that a positive number $r$ can be found such that the only solution to

$$f(0)=p\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$

that satisfies $\left | z \right | \leq r\,\,$ is $\,\,z=0$.

---

*Attempt of Proof*. $\,\,\,\,\,\,$  Given **Laurent's Theorem** which states that if $f$ is a holomorphic function on the annulus $\mathcal{A}(z_0,\,r_{in},\,r_{out})$, where $z_0$ is defined as its centre and $r_{out}$ width of outer radius and $r_{in}$ of inner, the *Laurent series* of $f$ on $\mathcal{A}$ converges to $f(z)$ on $\mathcal{A}$ :

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n \quad :\quad a_n=\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(\omega)}{(\omega-z_0)^{n+1}}d\omega$$

where $\gamma$ is any circle contained *within* $\mathcal{A}$. Apply $\mathcal{A}(z_0,0,r)$.

Consider two arbitrary points $z_i,\,z_j \in \mathcal{A}$ and obviously $z_i \neq z_j$ therefor. Assume that either of these points imply $f(z)=p\,$. Now, consider the Laurent series :

$$f(z_i)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{ni}(z_i-z_0)^n$$
$$f(z_j)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{nj}(z_j-z_0)^n.$$

Given that $a_{ni}=\int_{\gamma_i}\frac{f(\omega)}{(\omega-z_0)^{n+1}}d\omega\quad$ and $\quad a_{nj}=\int_{\gamma_j}\frac{f(\omega)}{(\omega-z_0)^{n+1}}d\omega$, $\,\,\,$applying $\gamma_i = \gamma_j$ implies $a_{ni}=a_{nj}:=\hat{a}_n$ and therefore

$$f(z_i)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{a}_n(z_i-z_0)^n$$
$$f(z_j)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{a}_n(z_j-z_0)^n$$.

Consider the difference $f(z_i)-f(z_j)$

$$f(z_i)-f(z_j)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{a}_n\underbrace{\left[(z_i-z_0)^n-(z_j-z_0)^n\right]}_{\neq 0 \,\, \forall n \quad \because \quad z_i \neq z_j}\neq 0$$

and thus, if e.g. $f(z_i)=p$, then $f(z_i)-f(z_j)=p-f(z_j)\neq 0$ and $f(z_j)\neq p\,$. Apply $z_i=0$ and $z_0=0$ Q.E.D

---

Is this approach made correctly? Thankful for all input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof cannot be correct, as it would show that generally $z_i \ne z_j$ implies that $f(z_i) \ne f(z_j)$, i.e. all holomorphic functions are injective, which is definitely wrong.

Essentially, you assume that for $z \ne 0$
$$
 f(z) - f(0)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \underbrace{z^n}_{\ne 0} 
$$
must be different from zero. This is a wrong conclusion, a simple counterexample is $f(z) = \sin(z)$.

But it is much simpler: Assume that such a positive number $r$ does not exist. Then for arbitrary $r > 0$ there is some $z \ne 0$ with $|z| < r$ and $f(z) = f(0)$. In particular, there is a sequence $(z_n)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = 0$ and
$$
 \forall n: z_n \ne 0 \,, \, f(z_n) = f(0) \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 f'(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(z_n) - f(0)}{z_n - 0} = 0 \, ,
$$
contrary to the assumption.